# What does this quote about git rebase mean?

Tags: git

I read it in this [interview](http://typicalprogrammer.com/linus-torvalds-goes-off-on-linux-and-git/) of Linus.

*Eventually you’ll discover the Easter egg in Git: all meaningful operations can be expressed in terms of the rebase command. Once you figure that out it all makes sense.*

It does not look like *just* a joke. Now I wonder how all operations can be expressed with *rebase*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [quora question](http://qr.ae/tsZxc) about this exact quote, the post is satire.

Coincidentally, expressing git operations with plumbing commands is actually quite easy, and pretty interesting. Check out [Chapter 10](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) in the git-scm book for some fun details. You'll learn a lot along the way.

Finally, you might be surprised to learn that `git rebase` is actually a set of sophisticated shell scripts. Read their source [here](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/git-rebase.sh), [here](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/git-rebase--am.sh), [here](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/git-rebase--interactive.sh), and [here](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/git-rebase--merge.sh). Following them through their operations is an excellent demonstration of git's core ethos: applying textual diffs in a arbitrary order. It's a great way to learn the more advanced concepts of commit reordering.